# Take the results from multiple sql queries and insert them inside a table

Tags: sql

I have these 3 queries

```
SELECT a.name
FROM customer1 a, customer2 b
WHERE a.id =  b.id

SELECT c.code
FROM segment1 c, orders e, country d, customer1 a
WHERE a.code_1 = b.code_2
AND c.segment1 = e.orders
AND c.segment1_id = 6

SELECT add.box, addr.address1, addr.address2
from customer1 a, infos addr, actions ac
WHERE a.account_id = addr.account_id
AND ac.deletion_status = 'N'
```

I want to combine the results from these 3 queries into one final table.

If I do something like that:

```
SELECT a.name, c.code, addr.box, addr.address1, addr.address2
FROM customer1 a, customer2 b, segment1 c, orders e, country d, infos addr, actions ac
WHERE a.id = b.id
AND a.code_1 = b.code_2
AND c.segment1 = e.orders
AND c.segment1_id = 6
AND ac.deletion_status = 'N'
```

Is this efficient? Do you recommend something else?

Comment: No, that's not going to work. Look into `union`.

Comment: Don't copy data between tables, create a view instead.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: @jarlh can you please provide me an example?

Comment: @jarlh when you are telling about views, you mean to create a view for each result set of these 3 queries and combine the views with inner join?

Comment: I'd consider a view that joins these 3 tables.

Comment: @jarlh Something like that?

` create view as new_table
 select a.name, c.code, addr.box, addr.address1, addr.address2
 from customer1  as a
 inner join
 customer2 as b,
 segment1 as c,
 orders as e,
 country as d,
 on c.segment1 = e.orders,
 a.id =  b.id,
 a.account_id = addr.account_id
 where
 c.segment1_id = 6
 c.deletion_status = 'N';  `

Comment: Does it return the result you expect? If yes, it's fine. (But you should really switch to modern, explicit JOIN syntax.)

Answer (score 2):

If you ask me, write a stored procedure, get the parameters, bring the tables you will use first, then join these results to other tables in the stored procedure, I think this is the most efficient method.If do you want I can give you an example.
 `CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_MyProcedure] @CustomerId int  AS BEGIN Declare @CustomerName nvarchar(50) Set @CustomerName=(SELECT Top 1 a.name FROM customer1 a, customer2 b WHERE a.id =  b.id and a.id=@CustomerId)SELECT c.code FROM segment1 c, orders e, country d, customer1 a WHERE a.code_1 = b.code_2 AND c.segment1 = e.orders AND c.segment1_id = 6 and a.name=@CustomerName END`

I wrote this example for your understanding, table numbers and parameters may increase.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response. Can you please provide me an example because I am not so familiar with sql. Thanks in advance